# ASP. NET global config changes limit number of threads and ignore timeout

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, timeout

Can I enforce at global level in a config file
possible number of active threads = 1 and 
ignore connection timeout (sometimes timeouts are set for few seconds - bothers me at debug).
Also If I accidentally make several requests the debug session goes haywire, going through the same method several times before finishing it, hence why i want to temporarily limit the number of threads allowed to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Test Environment (if you are testing on local machine)
but if you are deploying on IIS and testing then what you need to do is to configure the Application Pool to allow only 1 request and ignore the rest.

and for the timeout, you can also set timeout to max.

Hope this helps.